# Noun Phrase example? What exactly is phrase and clause?

Tags: noun-phrases

> Natalie adopted a cat that refused to meow.

I came across this example for a noun phrase but I don't understand how this can be a phrase when it has a subject and verb which perfectly agree with each other. Now I am also confused with the difference between phrase and clause. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **noun phrase** in the sentence is: 'a cat that refused to meow'. The various parts of the noun phrase are: an article ('a'); the noun itself ('cat'); and finally a descriptive **clause** ('that refused to meow').

Comment: Is it necessary for the subject and verb to agree with each other to form a clause? In the above a cat that refused to meow ;it has noun and verb.

Comment: There is already a subject (Natalie) and verb (adopted) in the larger sentence. The 'verb' 'refused' is not being used as a proper verb here in terms of the action happening immediately - it is used to describe the character of the cat, the descriptive clause functions in this way as an adjective. A slightly less interesting alternative sentence meaning much the same thing would be "Natalie adopted a silent cat".

Comment: Is there any way to identify what kind of phrase is it if a sentence is given? Any rules or tricks?

Comment: There are lots of different kinds - too many to talk about in a short answer or comment like this. Try: looking at a few sites here: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?hl=en&gws_rd=cr&ei=-WONVK26HMe9mgWvs4GICg#hl=en-AU&q=noun+phrases starting with [the wikipedia article on noun phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) if you haven't already read it.

Comment: A phrase is a group of words that belong (make sense) together: *a cat/refused to meow*. A clause is a complete thought but not always a complete sentence: ***that** refused to meow*. A sentence is a clause with a matching subject and predicate (*Natalie adopted a cat*), and it may have additional clauses as well. Check out this info on independent and dependent clauses: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/598/01/

Answer (score 1):

A noun phrase is a group of words with a noun as main element with other words added to it as "subelements" such as article, adjective, relative clause.

A clause is a sentence that is embedded into a sentence. Clauses contain subject and verbal part but they are not independent sentences.